# Tangent Space Projector from Riemannian Metric

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, projection, tangent-spaces

Consider a $d$-dimensional Riemannian manifold embedded in Euclidean space $\mathcal{M}\subset \mathbb{R}^N$ endowed with a metric $g$. We are given the Riemannian metric tensor $g_{ij}$ for this manifold. Is it then possible to derive the projector $\Pi_x:\mathbb{R}^N\to\mathcal{T}_x\mathcal{M}$ for each point $x\in\mathcal{M}$ which maps any ambient vector to the tangent space of $x$? If yes, would you be able to provide a way to do so?

Below I give an illustration of this (everything known except $\Pi_x$, $\mathcal{T}_x\mathcal{M}$ and naturally $v\in\mathcal{T}_x\mathcal{M}$):

[image]

Comment: $g$ is a riemannian metric on your embedded manifold or is it a riemannian metric on $\mathbb{R}^n$ ?

Comment: Perhaps we can consider a couple of cases: (i) metric of the manifold (e.g. sphere/hyperboloid), or (ii) computed as a pull-back metric. In principle, it should be as general as possible - we do not know the object globally but only the metric.

Comment: @TolgaBirdal What do you mean by "we don't know the object but only the metric"?

Comment: I mean the extrinsic nature of the manifold is unknown. It's not a sphere or any other well defined explicit geometry. We only know the metric at each point (and the points of course).

Comment: @TolgaBirdal That's part of the definition of the manifold, that there is no extrinsic nature. While you do always have a tangent space at each point even without a metric, its extrinsic appearance relies on the embedding.

Comment: True that. However, please assume that I can only access the metric. Can we derive the tangent space? (for instance metric might be obtained via a pull-back) For example, can we easily find a vector in the tangent space of $x$ given the metric?

Comment: I think your question is very unclear. The tangent space $T_xM$ is an intrinsic data of $M$, and so is its embedding in the ambient manifold (once the embedding is known). Also, a Riemannian metric acts on tangent vectors: how can you tell "we only know $g$, not $T_xM$"?

Comment: If the Riemannian metric of $M$ is given by the pullback of that of the ambient space then taking the orthogonal projection (with respect to the metric) onto $T_xM$ gives a natural projection. If the Riemannian metric is only defined on $M$, there is no way to identify a projection since we don't know any geometric information on the ambient space.

Comment: Ambient space is Euclidean though, $N$-dimensional. Sorry if I'm failing to be clearer here.

Comment: I do not like to say that we don't know $\mathcal{T}_x\mathcal{M}$. We just don't have direct acess to it. In fact the question is exactly that. It is implicitly there and I would like to define it given the metric. Said differently, maybe I would like to find (random/deterministic) vectors in the tangent space, given the metric.

Comment: I also find the question unclear: If you have an explicit embedding $M\to {\mathbb R}^N$ and a point $x\in M$, then you can explicitly compute $T_xM$ as a subspace of ${\mathbb R}^N$. If you do not have an explicit embedding and only the information about the induced metric $g$ on $M$ then one cannot solve the problem since  $g$ does not determine at embedding (even up to an extrinsic rigid motion of ${\mathbb R}^N$). But what do you need this projector for? Maybe your question will become clearer if you were to explain this.

Comment: Essentially, I would like to perform optimization (e.g. Riemannian gradient descent) on a manifold whose metric is given. This requires a projection onto the tangent space. The manifold is complex, but I can access the metric, numerically. Maybe my question is related to this one: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2979055/how-to-recover-the-tangent-space-from-the-metric ?

Comment: @TolgaBirdal Yes, the same hopeless question.

Comment: Though this should be possible under certain circumstances. For example, I could in principle solve for the logarithmic/exponential maps by solving the geodesic equations. Then, I can map random points on the manifold to the tangent space by the log-map and fit a hyperplane to get the normal vector. This would be possible in libraries such as geomstats (https://geomstats.github.io/). I am just looking for an easier and maybe more principled way. I am also fine with approximations.

Comment: 1. Let me try to put it this way, maybe you will understand. The problem you are trying to solve is badly **underdetermined** and the space of solutions is infinite-dimensional. You have to explain what a "solution" would mean in these circumstances. 2. Edit **the post** to improve clarity. 3. What is your level of familiarity with differential geometry? Did you read a textbook (this is what I would recommend) or simply picked up things here and there?

Comment: I did both actually, but appologies, maybe without the larger context missing, the question remained vague. I will now rephrase the question.

Answer (score 0):

For each $x\in M$, $T_xM$ can be realized as an linear subvariety of $\mathbb{R}^N$ (a $d$-plane which doesn't necessarily contain the origin), so every point $u\in \mathbb{R}^N$ has an orthogonal projection on $T_x M$, which is the point of $T_x M$ closer to $u$.

This point is obtained considering $u-x$ (the vector joining $x$ and $u$, which is a vector based at $x$) and decomposing as a sum of a vector tangent to $M$ and one orthogonal to it. Then you sum the tangent part to $x$ and obtain the orthogonal projection of $u$.

Comment: Sorry: (i) you can view $u$ to be directly defined on $x$ (like a gradient of a function), e.g. you can safely treat $x$ as the origin if you like; (ii) I guess my question relates to how one could decompose $u$ only knowing the Riemannian metric $g$ -- we do not yet know $\mathcal{T}_x\mathcal{M}$.